# Meijer function as a product of two Meijer's functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to evaluate an integral $I_1$ defined in $Eq.(1)$ as

\begin{align}
I_1=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\exp(-\beta x)K_1(\alpha x)}{1+x}dx\tag{1}
\end{align}
Where $K_1(.)$ is modified first order Bessel's function of second kind

In order to evaluate it, I went through transforming $\frac{x}{1+x}$ and $K_1(\alpha x)$ in terms of [Meijer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function) functions, which has been verified in MATHEMATICA and MUPAD

\begin{align}
\frac{x}{1+x}=G_{1,1}^{1,1}\bigg(x\bigg|_{1}^{1}\bigg)\tag{2}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
K_1(\alpha x)=\exp (\alpha x)\sqrt{\pi}G_{1,2}^{2,0}\bigg(2\alpha x\bigg|_{1, -1}^{1/2}\bigg)\tag{3}
\end{align}

thereby rewriting $Eq.(1)$ as $I_2$ from $Eq.(2)$ and $Eq.(3)$
\begin{align}
I_2=\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-\phi x)G_{1,1}^{1,1}\bigg(x\bigg|_{1}^{1}\bigg)G_{1,2}^{2,0}\bigg(2\alpha x\bigg|_{1, -1}^{1/2}\bigg)dx\tag{4}
\end{align}
where
$\phi = \beta - \alpha$

Now in order to proceed further I need to have a single Meijer function for the product of above two Meijer's function i.e.

\begin{align}
G_{pq}^{mn}\bigg(\theta x\bigg|_{b_1,b_2,...,b_q}^{a_1,a_2,...,a_p}\bigg)=G_{1,1}^{1,1}\bigg(x\bigg|_{1}^{1}\bigg)G_{1,2}^{2,0}\bigg(2\alpha x\bigg|_{1, -1}^{1/2}\bigg)\tag{5}
\end{align}

From $Eq.(5)$ and $Eq.(4)$, I can evaluate the above integral as
\begin{align}
I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-\phi x)G_{p,q}^{m,n}\bigg(\theta x\bigg|_{b_1,b_2,...,b_q}^{a_1,a_2,...,a_p}\bigg)dx
=\frac{1}{\phi}G_{p+1,q}^{m,n+1}\bigg(\frac{\theta}{\phi} \bigg|_{b_1,b_2,...,b_q}^{0,a_1,a_2,...,a_p}\bigg)\tag{6}
\end{align}

Solution to integral is from $[Eq.7.813.1]$,  Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik, 8e

Here what I've tried at MATHEMATICA

```
MeijerG[{{1}, {}}, {{1}, {}}, x] Exp[\[Alpha]x] Sqrt[\[Pi]] MeijerG[{{}, {1/2}}, {{1, -1}, {}}, 2 \[Alpha]x]
```

which results into

\begin{align}
\frac{xK_1(\alpha x)}{1+x}
\end{align}

Instead of this I want a single Meijer's G function representation of it.

Comment: Look at: http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/22/04/     the bottom formula.   In (4) above convert the exponential to G() and _if_ you meet the conditions you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the book "The H-Function with Applications in Statistics and Other Disciplines, (authors: A.M. Mathai, R.K. Saxena) page 32, equation (2.6.2)". As we already know, Meijer-G is the special case of Fox's H-Function. In the book part that I have mentioned, the solution exist for such integrals:

$$\int_0^{\infty}x^qe^{px-1}G_{a,b}^{c,d}\left(\omega x\vert \begin{matrix}\mathbf{k} \\ \mathbf{l} \end{matrix}\right)\left( \mu x\vert \begin{matrix}\mathbf{m} \\ \mathbf{n} \end{matrix}\right)dx$$
So the expression in the book completely affords your need.

Comment: Hi, I already solved it. Do have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1835651/270251