# Definite integral involving algebraic, exponential, and product of two Meijer's G function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions

I am having trouble with calculating the following integral:

\begin{equation}
I = \int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp({-\beta x})\large{G}_{2,2}^{1,2}\left( x \left| \begin{array}{cc} 1,1 \\ 1,0 \end{array} \right. \right) \large{G}_{1,2}^{2,0}\left( 2\alpha \sqrt{ab}x \left| \begin{array}{cc} 1/2 \\ v,-v \end{array} \right. \right)dx
\end{equation}

where $\beta$, $\alpha$, $a$, $b$ are non-zero positive constants, and $v \in \{0,1\}$. Any ideas or references would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, here is the solution.

Step 1: Expressing the product of two Meijer G function using an identity from 
http://functions.wolfram.com/07.34.16.0003.01

\begin{align}
G_{2,2}^{1,2}\left(x\Bigg\vert\begin{matrix}1,1\cr 1,0\end{matrix}\right)G_{1,2}^{2,0}\left(2\alpha\sqrt{ab}x\Bigg\vert\begin{matrix}1/2\cr v,-v\end{matrix}\right) = 
G_{0,0:2,2:1,2}^{0,0:1,2:2,0}\left(\begin{matrix}-\cr -\end{matrix}\Bigg\vert\begin{matrix}1,1\cr 1,0\end{matrix}\Bigg\vert\begin{matrix}1/2\cr v,-v\end{matrix}\Bigg\vert x,2\alpha\sqrt{ab}x\right)
\end{align}

Step 2: Expressing above result using extended generalized
bivariate Meijer G-function (EGBMGF) from "Sharma, B.L. and Abiodun, R.F.A.: ‘Generating function for generalized function of two variables’ Proc. American Mathematical Society, Oct. 1974, 46, (1), pp. 69-72"
\begin{align}
G_{0,0:2,2:1,2}^{0,0:1,2:2,0}\left(\begin{matrix}-\cr -\end{matrix}\Bigg\vert\begin{matrix}1,1\cr 1,0\end{matrix}\Bigg\vert\begin{matrix}1/2\cr v,-v\end{matrix}\Bigg\vert x,2\alpha\sqrt{ab}x\right)=&S\bigg[x,2\alpha\sqrt{ab}x\bigg\vert\bigg[\begin{matrix}
 0,0\cr0,0
 \end{matrix}\bigg]\begin{matrix}
 -\cr-
 \end{matrix}\bigg\vert\bigg(\begin{matrix}
 1,2\cr2,2
 \end{matrix}\bigg)\begin{matrix}
 1,1\cr1,0
 \end{matrix}\bigg\vert\bigg(\begin{matrix}
 2,0\cr1,2
 \end{matrix}\bigg)\begin{matrix}
 1/2\cr v,-v
 \end{matrix}\bigg]
\end{align}
Step 3: Expressing the above results from "Shah, M.: ’On generalization of some results and their applications’ Collectanea Mathematica, 1973, 24, (3), pp. 249-266"
\begin{align}
S\bigg[x,2\alpha\sqrt{ab}x\bigg\vert\bigg[\begin{matrix}
 0,0\cr0,0
 \end{matrix}\bigg]\begin{matrix}
 -\cr-
 \end{matrix}\bigg\vert\bigg(\begin{matrix}
 1,2\cr2,2
 \end{matrix}\bigg)\begin{matrix}
 1,1\cr1,0
 \end{matrix}\bigg\vert\bigg(\begin{matrix}
 2,0\cr1,2
 \end{matrix}\bigg)\begin{matrix}
 1/2\cr v,-v
 \end{matrix}\bigg]=&S\left[\begin{matrix}\label{shaheq}
 \left[\begin{matrix}
 0,0\cr0,0
 \end{matrix}\right]\cr\left(\begin{matrix}
 2,1\cr0,1
 \end{matrix}\right)\cr\left(\begin{matrix}
 0,2\cr1,0
 \end{matrix}\right)
 \end{matrix}\left\vert\begin{matrix}
 -;-\cr(1,1);(1,0)\cr(1/2);(v,-v)
 \end{matrix}\right\vert\begin{matrix}
 x\cr2\alpha\sqrt{ab}x
 \end{matrix}
 \right]
\end{align}

Step 4: Using an identity from "Shah, M.: ’On generalization of some results and their applications’ Collectanea Mathematica, 1973, 24, (3), pp. 249-266"

\begin{align}
I&=\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp(-\beta x)S\left[\begin{matrix}
\left[\begin{matrix}
0,0\cr0,0
\end{matrix}\right]\cr\left(\begin{matrix}
2,1\cr0,1
\end{matrix}\right)\cr\left(\begin{matrix}
0,2\cr1,0
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{matrix}\left\vert\begin{matrix}
-;-\cr(1,1);(1,0)\cr(1/2);(v,-v)
\end{matrix}\right\vert\begin{matrix}
x\cr2\alpha\sqrt{ab}x
\end{matrix}
\right]dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\beta^2}S\left[\begin{matrix}
\left[\begin{matrix}
1,0\cr1,0
\end{matrix}\right]\cr\left(\begin{matrix}
2,1\cr0,1
\end{matrix}\right)\cr\left(\begin{matrix}
0,2\cr1,0
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{matrix}\left\vert\begin{matrix}
2;-\cr(1,1);(1,0)\cr(1/2);(v,-v)
\end{matrix}\right\vert\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{\beta}\cr\frac{2\alpha\sqrt{ab}}{\beta}
\end{matrix}
\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\beta^2}G_{1,0:2,2:1,2}^{1,0:1,2:2,0}\Bigg(2\Bigg\vert\begin{matrix}
1,1\cr 1,0\end{matrix}\Bigg\vert\begin{matrix}1/2\cr v,-v\end{matrix}\Bigg\vert\frac{1}{\beta},\frac{2\alpha\sqrt{ab}}{\beta}\Bigg)
\end{align}

That completes the proof.